# Unable to upload files. Though the maximum file size limit is 80 MB, can't upload even 50 kb files

Tags: ajax, files

I copied a site from localhost to AWS server. I can easily upload files in localhost but when I try uploading in the live site it gives me the error

*`"An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (80 MB) that this server supports."`*

In `php.ini` and .`htaccess` and `settings.php` I have changed `upload_max_filesize` to 80MB and `post_max_size` to 164 MB.

And according to [this link](http://drupal.org/node/1928574#comment-7130928), , I also disabled mod_security module in apache.

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/1928574#comment-7118420)  it says, this could be AJAX/Jquery error.

Is there something else that could be the cause for this error?

Comment: Note, it should be `upload_max_filesize = 80M` _not_ `upload_max_filesize = 80MB` (M vs MB) same with `post_max_size` Also, check your error logs for e.g suhosin patch error.

Comment: Too broad to be answered from afar. In the end it's Apache's mod_security. Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

Some things that can break file uploads:

- upload_max_filesize and post_max_size ;
- memory_limit ;
- Unwritable tmp directory.

Comment: I have already tried with increasing upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit. I have also given 777 permissions to tmp directory. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing MaxRequestLen to 80MB as well. You will need it done for you by the administrators if you use a shared host environment though.